# User assigned Managed identity with Credentials Deployment in Data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, arm, azure-data-factory, identity, managed

I am trying to deploy Credentials associated with User assigned managed identity to higher environment via DevOps and ARM templates.

I get the error: User assigned identity does not belong to the resource you are deploying to

I want to parametrize the User assigned managed identity resource id.

I added:

```
 "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials": {
    "properties": {
      "typeProperties": {
        "resourceid": "="
      }
    }
  }
```

to my ARM template definition in Data Factory, I am still not getting the UAMI as a parameter in the ARM file I exported.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: I hope you have assigned the required role to UAMI to access/connect with other resources.